# Do the tenses have to agree in this case?

Tags: grammar, tense, tense-agreement

Let's go straight to the point with this example:

> I was trying to figure out what this mess is/was about.

I know that the two verbs have to agree, so 'is' in this case sounds wrong. But I wanted to make sure that this rule applies even when the second clause refers to something that is still going on.

In this case, the speaker can still see the mess all around. So the mess ***is*** there now. Should I use 'was' nonetheless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no rule that requires the verb tenses in a sentence to agree, whatever **agree** means.

They just have to work together so that the grammar is correct and the sentence says what is intended. So, in your case:

If the mess persists, use the present tense.

If the mess has gone away/been cleared up, use the past tense.

You can still be trying to figure out (in the present) what the mess is about (present tense) or was about (past tense) or might be about, might have been about etc.

If you're not sure, use which ever you think is the better fit.

Answer (score 0):

> I **was** trying to figure out what this mess **is/was** about.

Have you figured it out or are you still in the process of figuring it out? Is the mess still present? Only you can know this. You can't have both **"is"** and **"was"** at the same time, for both **"trying"** to figure it out and for the **"mess"** itself. You can only apply "is" *or* "was" to each, not both "is" *and* "was" to both "trying" *and* to "mess".

> But I wanted to make sure that this rule applies even when the second
> clause refers to something that is still going on.

What is that "something"? You mean the "mess" and then some other kind of thing that's still present?

> In this case, the speaker can still see the mess all around. So the
> mess is there now.

It sounds to me like you're trying to get ahead of yourself, trying to say too many things at the same time, all with a single sentence. You can't say ahead of time that you have figured out something that doesn't even exist yet for you to begin figuring it out, or before it has ceased to exist or after it has ended.

As I understand this, the "mess" in your example is a thing, an object, or a situation, something you're trying to understand. When you're trying to "figure out", when you're trying to understand this thing, this object, or this situation... that's an event. You're working on understanding this thing you call "mess".

Use this if the mess is *still present* and you *have not* figured it out just yet but are working on it:

> I **am trying** to figure out what *this* mess **is** about.

Use this if the mess is *still present* and you *gave up* on trying to figure it out:

> I **tried** to figure out what *this* mess **is** about.

Use this if the mess *no longer exists* and you *failed to figure it out* while it was present:

> I **was trying** to figure out what *that* mess **was** about.

Use this if the mess *no longer exists* and you *successfully figured it out* while it was present:

> I **figured out** what *that* mess **was** about.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).